# Bigquery GA360 daily export: find earliest daily table

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

BigQuery shows me that a GA360 daily export view has 600+ days in it but the earliest day table in the dropdown menu is only 500 days ago. How many daily tables do I actually have and how can I see the earliest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the dropdown menu only shows the last 500 tables, so if you are looking to find the first ever table you can't just look at the earliest table in the dropdown. Instead, you can run:

`SELECT table_id
  FROM <dataset-name>:<view-number>.__TABLES_SUMMARY__
  ORDER BY table_id`

to find the earliest table name.

Comment: Would `SELECT
  min(table_id)
FROM
  <dataset-name>:<view-number>.__TABLES_SUMMARY__` work too? Would save you doing the order and you get just one table name back.

Comment: Yeah, though I have a few dummy tables in there that are alphabetically smaller than ga_sessions.

Comment: Get rid of them. Shouldn't have dummy tables ;-)\